# Ajax function: data fields with multiple value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a doubt about the data fields of ajax function.

Usually, we have that a syntax for ajax function may be:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/aaa/bbb/ccc",
        method: "SomeMethod",
        data: someData,
        success: function (response) {
        do something
    }
```

My question is: in data fields, can i put more than one data? In other words, can I pass from:

```
data: someData,
```

to:

```
data: data1, data2, data3...
```

and so on?

Comment: You can send data as associative array.

Comment: @luca Sepe you can pass json also,provided you handle that in your server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can build multiple params, hold them in an `object` and send them as `JSON.stringify()`:

```
var paramsToSend = {};
paramsToSend['data1'] = 'data1';
paramsToSend['data2'] = 'data2';
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {params:JSON.stringify(paramsToSend)},
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an object that holds the data. `data: {date1Name: data1Value, date2Name: data2Value}`.

Your complete code should look like this.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/aaa/bbb/ccc",
        method: "SomeMethod",
        data: {date1Name: data1Value, date2Name: data2Value},
        success: function (response) {
        do something
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an object of key/value pairs.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data : { data1: 'bar', data2: 'foo' },
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/aaa/bbb/ccc",
    method: "SomeMethod",
    data: "name=value&name1=value1&name2=value2",
    success: function (response) {
      //do something
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/aaa/bbb/ccc",
    method: "SomeMethod",
    data: {name : 'Luca', country : 'NA'},
    success: function (response) {}

})
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to pass it as an array?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/aaa/bbb/ccc",
    method: "SomeMethod",
    data: { data:[data1, data2, data3] },
    success: function (response) {
    do something
}
```

I would recommend putting the array in a dictionary / JSON object so you have a variable name to key off of in whatever backend language you are using.